# Akka version conflict when running test command in sbt shell

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

i'm trying to run a test command in sbt-shell of intellij ide for this -> [https://github.com/theiterators/akka-http-microservice#akka-http-microservice-example] project then it shows Akka version conflict. how to resolve it?

this is build.sbt

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging , GatlingPlugin)


name := "akka-http-microservice"
organization := "com.theiterators"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.13.5"

scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8",
"-target:jvm-1.8",
"-feature",
"-language:implicitConversions",
"-language:postfixOps")

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaHttpV      = "10.2.4"
  val akkaV          = "2.6.14"
  val scalaTestV     = "3.2.8"
  val circeV         = "0.13.0"
  val akkaHttpCirceV = "1.36.0"
  val gatlingVersion = "3.5.1"


  Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaV,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaV,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % akkaHttpV,
    "io.circe"          %% "circe-core" % circeV,
    "io.circe"          %% "circe-generic" % circeV,
    "de.heikoseeberger" %% "akka-http-circe" % akkaHttpCirceV,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaV,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % akkaHttpV % "test",
    "org.scalatest"     %% "scalatest" % scalaTestV % "test",
    "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % gatlingVersion % "test,it",
    "io.gatling"            % "gatling-test-framework"    % gatlingVersion % "test,it"

  )
}

Revolver.settings
```

this is plugin.sbt

```
 addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.9.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.15.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.8.1")

addSbtPlugin("io.gatling" % "gatling-sbt" % "3.2.2")

addSbtPlugin("io.gatling" % "gatling-sbt" % "MANUALLY_REPLACE_WITH_LATEST_VERSION")
```

this is service specification

```
import akka.event.NoLogging
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentTypes._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{HttpRequest, HttpResponse}
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes._
import akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AsyncFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

class ServiceSpec extends AsyncFlatSpec with Matchers with ScalatestRouteTest with Service with Protocols {
  override def testConfigSource = "akka.loglevel = WARNING"
  override def config = testConfig
  override val logger = NoLogging

  val ip1Info = IpInfo("8.8.8.8", Option("United States"), Option("Mountain View"), Option(37.386), Option(-122.0838))
  val ip2Info = IpInfo("8.8.4.4", Option("United States"), None, Option(38.0), Option(-97.0))
  val ipPairSummary = IpPairSummary(ip1Info, ip2Info)

  override lazy val ipApiConnectionFlow = Flow[HttpRequest].map { request =>
    if (request.uri.toString().endsWith(ip1Info.query))
      HttpResponse(status = OK, entity = marshal(ip1Info))
    else if(request.uri.toString().endsWith(ip2Info.query))
      HttpResponse(status = OK, entity = marshal(ip2Info))
    else
      HttpResponse(status = BadRequest, entity = marshal("Bad ip format"))
  }

  "Service" should "respond to single IP query" in {
    Get(s"/ip/${ip1Info.query}") ~> routes ~> check {
      status shouldBe OK
      contentType shouldBe `application/json`
      responseAs[IpInfo] shouldBe ip1Info
    }

    Get(s"/ip/${ip2Info.query}") ~> routes ~> check {
      status shouldBe OK
      contentType shouldBe `application/json`
      responseAs[IpInfo] shouldBe ip2Info
    }
  }

  it should "respond to IP pair query" in {
    Post(s"/ip", IpPairSummaryRequest(ip1Info.query, ip2Info.query)) ~> routes ~> check {
      status shouldBe OK
      contentType shouldBe `application/json`
      responseAs[IpPairSummary] shouldBe ipPairSummary
    }
  }

  it should "respond with bad request on incorrect IP format" in {
    Get("/ip/asdfg") ~> routes ~> check {
      status shouldBe BadRequest
      responseAs[String].length should be > 0
    }

    Post(s"/ip", IpPairSummaryRequest(ip1Info.query, "asdfg")) ~> routes ~> check {
      status shouldBe BadRequest
      responseAs[String].length should be > 0
    }

    Post(s"/ip", IpPairSummaryRequest("asdfg", ip1Info.query)) ~> routes ~> check {
      status shouldBe BadRequest
      responseAs[String].length should be > 0
    }
  }
}
```

Error given below--

```
[info] ServiceSpec *** ABORTED ***
[info]   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are using version 2.6.14 of Akka, but it appears you (perhaps indirectly) also depend on older versions of related artifacts. You can solve this by adding an explicit dependency on version 2.6.14 of the [akka-slf4j] artifacts to your project. Here's a complete collection of detected artifacts: (2.6.11, [akka-slf4j]), (2.6.14, [akka-actor, akka-protobuf-v3, akka-stream, akka-testkit]). See also: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/common/binary-compatibility-rules.html#mixed-versioning-is-not-allowed
[info]   at akka.util.ManifestInfo.checkSameVersion(ManifestInfo.scala:184)
[info]   at akka.util.ManifestInfo.checkSameVersion(ManifestInfo.scala:162)
[info]   at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:1033)
[info]   at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:1022)
[info]   at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:1022)
[info]   at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:1045)
[info]   at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:272)
[info]   at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:316)
[info]   at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:290)
[info]   at akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.RouteTest.createActorSystem(RouteTest.scala:36)
[info]   ...
[info] Run completed in 1 second, 568 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 1
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] *** 1 SUITE ABORTED ***
[error] Error during tests:
[error]         ServiceSpec
[error] (Test / test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 8 s, completed 22 Apr. 2021, 3:14:59 pm
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % akkaV
```

to the `Seq` in your `libraryDependencies` block should resolve this.  In general in Akka it's best to not rely on transitive dependencies.